# What this const before method name mean?

Tags: c++

In one of our text-books it is suggested that we should use interfaces in C++ as a good design practice. They give below example;

```
class IAnimation
{
  public:
      virtual void VAdvance(const int deltaMilisec) = 0;
      virtual bool const VAtEnd() const = 0;
      virtual int const VGetPostition() const = 0;
};
```

I did not get the meaning of:

```
virtual bool const VAtEnd() const = 0;
virtual int const VGetPostition() const = 0;
```

I know const is used after () to make them invocable from const instances. But what const before VAtEnd and VGetPosition (method names) mean?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the code author is trying to make it hard for the code to be understood!

Comment: const binds to the left (unless it is on the very left then in binds right).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the return type is const, it's the same as:

```
virtual const bool VAtEnd() const = 0;
virtual const int VGetPostition() const = 0;
```

It has no practical meaning though, as the return value is copied anyway.

If you'd be returning an object though:

```
struct A
{
    void goo() {}
};

const A foo() {return A();}



int main()
{
    A x = foo();
    x.goo();      //ok
    foo().goo();  //error
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luchian Grigore. I must revise my C++ knowledge. By the way const bool is more intuitive. And yes since I am new here SOF asking me to wait for 9min before I can mark your post as answer :(.

Comment: It's there to prevent weirdness like : `VGetPostition() = 4` or any assigning to a function really. Don't know why you would want to do that though.

Comment: @Mahesha999: Which one is more readable is up to discussion, I prefer `const` on the right side because it is more consistent and thus takes less thinking effort. Consider `typedef int* intp;`, now `const int*` and `const intp` are different types, but `int* const` is the same as `intp const` (i.e. you can mentally substitute the type on the place of the typedef if you write `const` on the right side, but you cannot do that if `const` is on the left`

Comment: @Mahesha999: `const bool` is more intuitive if you happen to speak a language such as English that conventionally places adjectives before nouns. `bool const` is more consistent with other uses of `const` (e.g. `char const * const f() const`), where each `const` qualifies the identifier immediately before it.

Comment: It should be noted that returning objects by const value is not good practice, as it inhibits C++11 move semantics.