# what is the difference returning const or non-const in primative types c++

Tags: c++, return, constants

I've tried to understand what differs if I add const or ignore it while returning function. Let me explain my question through an example.

```
const int foo()
{
    return 3;
}

int main()
{
    int check;
    check=foo();
    cout<<"before:"<<check<<endl;
    check=1;
    cout<<"after:"<<check<<endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

Up to now, I always think that, since I write const foo() I dont be able to change the check varaible,however I compiled it and get no error.

I wonder what I gain or loose by writing const before my foo() function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It used to be advised to do so, to avoid accidentally assigning to the returned temporary: `foo() = 10; // fails to compile`. Now it is advised not to, as it inhibits move semantics (i.e. it means you have to copy the entire returned temporary into some local variable, rather than steal it. Not that it makes a difference in the primitive case, but as a general rule it's good). In your case, `check` is non-`const`, and is just given the same *value* as the `const` temporary returned by `foo`.

Comment: Possible dupllicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177904/what-this-const-before-method-name-mean

Comment: For rather strict definitions of "possible" - it's an exact dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `const` modifier on primitive return types will be ignored.

See also this question: [Should I return const objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051012/should-i-return-const-objects)

Answer (score 2):

You're not changing the variable. You're changing a copy of it.

```
check=foo();
```

assigns the value returned by `foo` to `check`. `check` is not `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is following compiler warning:

```
warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
const int foo()
              ^
```

See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a09dc9b8342b7d6b).

This type of thing is ignored, so it has no effect.

Comment: The difference is the warning.... very bad description. You should say WHY the warning is thrown...

Comment: @Zaibis if you actually read the warning, it tells you why.

Comment: So anyway you should mention it what is the reason that this happens.

Comment: @Zaibis so I should explain why a compiler follows the standard? The qualifiers on primitive types is ignored. There's not much more to it...

Comment: No but you could add that this is part of the standard, or just say that it has to be this way, because I would bet some one who is asking a question like OP isn't that confirm with the standard, so it would help some people ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will make difference when you will try to return a reference.

For example:

```
int gGlobal;

const int & func()
{
    return gGlobal;
}

int main ()
{
     //Following statement will give error.
     func() = 3;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an entirely different thing.

Comment: @jrok: Of course not, he's right.

Comment: @DídacPérez He is right, but it's not related to OP question.